# сделать минимальным значение в текстовом поле

Tags: javascript, input, counter

у меня есть 2 кнопки повышающие и уменьшающие значения поля на единицу, но при нажатии "уменьшить" значение опускается ниже 1, подскажите как сделать минимальным значение единицу, чтоб оно не опускалось при нажатии кнопки ниже 1?

```
<button class="btn-count" type="button" onclick="btnCountDown()">-</button>
<input type="number" min="1"  size="1" value="1" id="howMuch"  readonly>
<button class="btn-count" type="button" onclick="btnCountUp()">+</button>




var i=1;
function btnCountUp() {
    i++;
document.getElementById('howMuch').value= +i;

}

function btnCountDown() {
    i--;
    document.getElementById('howMuch').value= +i;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно ведь просто добавить **условие**:

```
if(document.getElementById('howMuch').value < 1) document.getElementById('howMuch').value = 1;
```

Или так:

```
document.getElementById('howMuch').value = i < 1 ? 1 : i;
```

В вашем коде:

```
var i=1;
function btnCountUp() {
i++;
document.getElementById('howMuch').value= +i;

}

function btnCountDown() {
    i--;
    document.getElementById('howMuch').value= +i;
    if(document.getElementById('howMuch').value < 1){
        document.getElementById('howMuch').value = 1;
        i = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо, строка с if ом в функции помогла, я что то подобное пытался сделать, но не вышло, оказывается все было просто

Answer (score 1):

Код изначально не верный. Проверяйте логику. Зачем инкремент и декремент? Также не рекомендую использовать глобальную переменную, плохая практика. Берите значение из элемента и с ним работайте.

```
function btnCountDown() {
    i--; # удалите это лишнее
    i = document.getElementById('howMuch').value
    # далее условие на минимальное значение, если меньше тогда ничего не происходит.
    if ( i > x){
        i--;
    }
    document.getElementById('howMuch').value = i;
}
```